# Trying to 'group' and flatten values from nested structure in clojure

Tags: clojure

Another restless night trying to figure out how to do this. Given the nested data structure which I've reformatted for readability looking for malformed declaration:

```
(def tm (list 
          {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :child (list 
               {:a 4 :b 5 :c 6 :child (list 
                     {:a 40 :b 50 :c 60 :child (list {:a nil :b nil :c nil})})}                                                                                               
               {:a 70 :b 80 :c 90 :child (list {:a nil :b nil :c nil})})} 
          {:a 400 :b 500 :c 600 :child (list {:a nil :b nil :c nil})}
          {:a 7 :b 8 :c 9 :child (list 
               {:a 10 :b 11 :c 12 :child (list {:a nil :b nil :c nil})})})
  )
```

And the traversal can be seen in **dg123** example below

I'm getting the following:

```
=>(roll-down tm :a)
((1 4 40) (1 70) (7 10))
```

But was expecting:

```
((1 4 40) (1 70) (400) (7 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more functional approach that doesn't use mutable state:

```
(defn roll-down-helper [c kw]
  (when-let [root-val (kw c)]
    (cons root-val
          (filter (comp not nil?)
                  (for [node (:child c)]
                    (roll-down-helper node kw))))))

(defn get-paths [[x & ys]]
  (if (empty? ys)
    (list (list x))
    (for [y ys]
      (flatten (cons x y)))))


(defn roll-down [c kw]
  (apply concat
   (map (comp get-paths #(roll-down-helper % kw)) c)))
```

Then you can do the following:

```
user> (roll-down tm :a)
((1 4 40) (1 70) (400) (7 10))
user> (roll-down tm :b)
((2 5 50) (2 80) (500) (8 11))
user> (roll-down tm :c)
((3 6 60) (3 90) (600) (9 12))
```

Comment: I marked this as answered however it I were to add more children to {:a 4 b: 5 :c 6} it does not follow the branch.

Comment: @Frank C What about if you move the `}` at the end of `:c 60` to the end of its `:child` list like in all the other nodes in your `tm` data structure? I didn't see it before, but it looks like that part of the data structure is malformed.

Comment: I've reformatted and touched the structure as now shown in the question and am getting slightly different but not complete results. Count on the struct returns 3 as expected.

Comment: @FrankC. I updated my answer and it should be working properly now. `get-paths` wasn't properly handling the case in which the list passed in only has one element.

Comment: Thats the winner! Much appreciated, I'll have to study it for a while to get it to sink in. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a zippers based solution

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn root-to-leaf-paths [t]
   (loop [t t paths []] 
     (cond 
       (z/end? t) paths
       (z/branch? t) (recur (z/next t) paths) 
       :leaf (recur (z/next t) (conj paths (z/path t))))))

(defn roll-down [d kw]
   (->> (z/zipper :child :child nil {:child d})
        (root-to-leaf-paths)
        (map (comp rest (partial map kw)))))
```

Note: Your `tm` isn't a tree but a list of trees. So, here we first turn this structure into a tree by placing the list of trees under one parent root `{:child d}`. Then we drop this from the resulting paths `(comp rest ...)`.

Examples

```
(roll-down tm :a)
;=> ((1 4 40) (1 70) (400) (7 10))

(roll-down tm :b)
;=> ((2 5 50) (2 80) (500) (8 11))

(roll-down tm :c)
;=> ((3 6 60) (3 90) (600) (9 12))
```

Comment: Like this one too. I will try it out and time it although I think it will be a 'run-once' function to establish initial system state.

Answer (score 2):

a short version use `mapcat`:

```
(defn roll-down [g k]
  (mapcat
   #(if-let [c (:child %)]
      (map (fn [x] (conj x (k %))) (roll-down c k))
      [[(k %)]])
   g))

-> (roll-down tm :a)
([nil 40 4 1] [nil 70 1] [nil 400] [nil 10 7])
```

This solution uses a depth first traverse and also treat `nil` as a path. If you like you can just do a `remove` and `reverse` on the result.

Comment: After multiple iterations (with the remove included) this performs as well as the zipper example. I also like the depth first result as it actually aligns to what I was trying to do. +1 for the answer!

Comment: btw: I ended up using 'subvec' to eliminate the nil.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply map your extractor onto your data

```
(defn get-as [tm] 
  (let [results (atom [])]
    (clojure.walk/prewalk
     #(do (if-let [uid (:a %)] 
            (swap! results conj :a (:a %))) 
          %)
     tm)
    @results))

(map get-as tm) ; => ([:a 1 :a 4] [:a 7 :a 10])
```

Comment: I've edited the question as it did not quite articulate it well enough.